# caffe data layer example step by step

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I want to find a caffe python data layer example to learn.
I know that Fast-RCNN has a python data layer, but it's rather complicated since I
am not familiar with object detection.
So my question is, is there a python data layer example where I can learn how to define my own data preparation procedure?
For example, how to do define a python data layer do much more data augmentation
(such as translation, rotation etc.) than caffe `"ImageDataLayer"`.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a `"Python"` layer: a layer implemented in python to feed data into your net. (See an example for adding a `type: "Python"` layer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34922529/1714410)).

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, os.environ['CAFFE_ROOT']+'/python')
import caffe
class myInputLayer(caffe.Layer):
  def setup(self,bottom,top):
    # read parameters from `self.param_str`
    ...
  def reshape(self,bottom,top):
    # no "bottom"s for input layer
    if len(bottom)>0:
      raise Exception('cannot have bottoms for input layer')
    # make sure you have the right number of "top"s
    if len(top)!= ...
       raise ...
    top[0].reshape( ... ) # reshape the outputs to the proper sizes
    
  def forward(self,bottom,top): 
    # do your magic here... feed **one** batch to `top`
    top[0].data[...] = one_batch_of_data


  def backward(self, top, propagate_down, bottom):
    # no back-prop for input layers
    pass
```

For more information on `param_str` see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34588801/1714410).
You can find a sketch of a data loading layer with pre-fetch [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48065550/1714410).

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, I will try to implement one and post my code here. o(^▽^)o

Comment: In fact I find one PR at caffe website. https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/3471/files

Comment: Is it possible to use multithreading here, to load data quicker?

Comment: @kishensurajP you can use Python threading module to prefetch data.

Comment: Thanks. So there has to be a loop for the total number of images in the batch within the forward method, so that top[0].data[...] outputs the full batch?

Comment: @Alex yes. each call of forward must   yield a new batch

Comment: @Shai: that's cool. Do yo know any way to speed up the loop over images in the batch? Something like itertools?

Comment: @Alex you may try speed things up using `multiprocessing.Process` to fetch the data. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48065550/1714410) for a sketch.

Answer (score 5):

@Shai's answer is great. At the same time, I find another detailed example about python data layer in one PR of caffe-master. https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/3471/files
I hope this detailed example be helpful for anyone else.

Comment: Thank you very much, do you happen to know how we should configure the prototxt file? actually I am trying to do exactly what you asked, but I am confused. even after looking at the code. 
my problem is first how we define the image source in the prototxt and then how we read different parameters from it. 
I would appreciate if you could share your implementation with us. it helps us greatly.

Comment: Done it :) Thank you very much for your link. I followed couple of Shais answer and could thanks to dear God, get every thing running :)