# How to use data different than images with Caffe?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe

I have seen lots of examples showing how to insert image data for model training in Caffe.

I am trying to train a model using data that is not images. I can reshape it as a matrix or a vector (for every example), but I don't understand how to make my Caffe network read it.

I know that Caffe can work with lmdb/hdf5 databases, and I can additionally use a Python data layer.
I guess a Python data layer will be my best choice. Can someone provide an example of how to create some kind of array in Python and use it as training data for a Caffe model?

Comment: if you are interested in an input python layer, you might find [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34996075/1714410) relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to create a python layer for simple vector inputs. HDF5 layer is probably easiest to work with. Just create HDF5 files with your favorite tool ( Refer [this](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/matlab/hdf5creation) for creating HDF5 using matlab, or [this](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/brewing-logreg.ipynb) for creating using python)

Both examples are fairly easy to follow. The matlab example gives you a more *advanced* version of HDF5 file creation--as in creating batches and all--but at its heart you just need to call

```
store2hdf5(filename, data, labels) %others are optional
```

Similarly, the python example also goes over complete example, all of which you may or may not need. At its core, creating HDF5 file is simply.

```
import h5py
with h5py.File('filename.h5', 'w') as f:
    f['data'] = your_data
    f['label'] = your_labels
```

You can easily use the file thus created in HDF5 Datalayer easily as follows. You just need to create a text file with list of HDF5 files you want to use.

```
layer {
name: "data"
type: "HDF5Data"
top: "data"
top: "label"
include {
phase: TRAIN
}
hdf5_data_param {
source: "path_to_text_file_containing_list_of_HDF5_Files.txt" #
batch_size: 128
shuffle: true
}
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Could not ask for any better answer... So what is the use case of a python layer?

Comment: It's mainly used for writing functionalities that are beyond what is provided by caffe. If I answered your question, it would be great if you marked it as answered.

Comment: @Prophecies I do it similar to your example however I have an error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930478/caffe-doesnt-read-the-hdf5-files-for-test-phase-instead-reads-the-path-given-i    All the examples I have come across use "data" and "label" to name their tops but I have 3 tops so I have created specific names, it shouldn't be -but could it be the reason? If so how can I name them for 3 tops?