# Caffe Python Layer for input, set data type to uint8

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to train a CNN in caffe.  I wanted to do a lot of data augmentation, so I'm using a `"Python"` layer for input, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996075/caffe-data-layer-example-step-by-step).

However, I see from the log that Caffe is using the datatype `float32` for all my data.  This is really wasteful, because I'm only dealing with 8-bit integers.  Is there a way to tell caffe to use `dtype='uint8'`?

I have tried to typecast the data while setting the top:

```
top[0].data[...] = someArray.astype(np.uint8, copy=False)
```

but this doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, caffe is currently compiled to support only float32 or float64. I suppose `lmdb`/`leveldb` data can be stored in `uint8` format, but caffe converts it internally to `float32` upon reading.
The fact that your input data is `uint8` does not mean the entire processing remains this way, at the first convolution/InnerProduct layer, data is multiplied with float numbers and can no longer be guaranteed to remain `uint8`.
So, I suppose you should put up with the little space waste at the input layer and give up the conversion to `uint8`.

Comment: Ok I guess you're right, I would anyway make savings only in the input layer, it's totally not worth the effort.

Sorry I can't upvote, I don't have enough reputation. :)