# How to read hdf5 with python layer in caffe and do data augmentation?

Tags: python, crop, caffe, hdf5, mirror

I want to read data from `hdf5` file and do data augmentation.

I can do data augmentation in `transform_param` with mirror and crop.

However,I cannot have `transformation_param` in a `HDF5Data` layer - caffe does not support this.

I consider it might be a good way to write a python layer to solve it. Read data from hdf5 file and do data augmentation at the same time.

I have read some relevant answers such as "[caffe data layer example step by step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996075/caffe-data-layer-example-step-by-step)" and "[What is a Python layer in caffe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41344168/what-is-a-python-layer-in-caffe)"

I still don't know some details such as where should I put the written file`"*.py"`? And how to write the codes to do data augmentation?

Answer (score 0):

You python layer `*.py` should be in your `$PYTHONPATH`.

Consider examples of python layers in `$CAFFE_ROOT/examples/pycaffe/layers`
,for custom python loss and data layer.

Consider particularly in `$CAFFE_ROOT/examples/pycaffe/layers/pascal_multilabel_datalayers.py`

Before next batch gets loaded, you can do the data augmentation on the fly.

Then in `*.prototxt`

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "Python"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  python_param {
    module: "pascalcontext_layers"
    layer: "PASCALContextSegDataLayer"
    param_str: "{\'context_dir\': \'../../data/pascal-context\', \'seed\': 1337, \'split\': \'train\', \'voc_dir\': \'../../data/pascal\'}"
  }
}
```

`module` is the file name and `layer` is the class name.

Comment: Thanks for answering!  I've tried this and found 'Check failed: registry.count(type) == 1 (0 vs. 1) Unknown layer type: Python'. However, I    'list(caffe.layer_type_list())' and find 'python' in this list. Why?

Comment: You have to compile your caffe with `WITH_PYTHON_LAYER := 1`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41344168/what-is-a-python-layer-in-caffe?noredirect=1&lq=1 for details

Comment: I've compile that. I find 'python' when I run `list(caffe.layer_type_list())`. Maybe caffe just can't find it?