# Using Memory DataLayer in Caffe gives "data_ MemoryDataLayer needs to be initalized by calling Reset"

Tags: caffe

I'm planning to do real-time augmentation in `caffe`. and these are the steps I have taken so far:
1.Replace `Data` layer with `MemoryData` in the network:

```
name: "test_network"
layer {
  name: "cifar"
  type: "MemoryData"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  memory_data_param {
   batch_size: 32
   channels: 3
   height: 32
   width: 32
  }

}
layer {
  name: "cifar"
  type: "MemoryData"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
   memory_data_param {
   batch_size: 32
   channels: 3
   height: 32
   width: 32
  }
}
```

and this is the code for training :

```
caffe.set_mode_gpu()
maxIter = 100
batch_size = 32
j = 0
for i in range(maxIter):
    #fetch images 
    batch = seq.augment_images(np.transpose(data_train[j: j+batch_size],(0,2,3,1)))
    print('batch-{0}-{1}'.format(j,j+batch_size))
    #set input and solve
    batch = batch.reshape(-1,3,32,32).astype(np.float32)
    net.set_input_arrays(batch, label_train[j: j+batch_size].astype(np.float32))
    j = j + batch_size + 1
    solver.step(1)
```

but when the code reaches to the net.set_input_arrays(), it crashes with this error:

```
W0405 20:53:19.679730  4640 memory_data_layer.cpp:90] MemoryData does not transform array data on Reset()
I0405 20:53:19.713727  4640 solver.cpp:337] Iteration 0, Testing net (#0)
I0405 20:53:19.719229  4640 net.cpp:685] Ignoring source layer accuracy_training
F0405 20:53:19.719229  4640 memory_data_layer.cpp:110] Check failed: data_ MemoryDataLayer needs to be initalized by calling Reset
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
```

I cant find the reset() method, what should I do ?

Comment: Spelling fixed long time ago at https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/commit/09546dbe9130789f0571a76a36b0fc265cd81fe3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `MemoryDataLayer` in `Caffe` is not meant to be used through `pycaffe` interface.

> Yeah it's discouraged to use the MemoryDataLayer in Python. Using it
>   also transfers memory ownership from Python to C++ with the Boost
>   bindings and therefore causes memory leaks. Memory will only be
>   released after the network object is destructed in python. So if
>   you're training a network for a long time, you'll run out of memory.
>   It's encouraged to use InputLayer instead, where you can just assign
>   data from a numpy array into the memory blobs.

[Link](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/5493#issuecomment-292271665)
As for the solution, [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996075/caffe-data-layer-example-step-by-step) would be nice alternatives.