# How to create on-the-fly python layer for calculating class weights in caffe?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I want to add a python layer that calculates probability matrix `H` for `INfoGainLoss Layer` on-the-fly. I have already wrote the program for creating this matrix by calculating probabilities of each class of one image and saving it into `.binaryproto` file. I really appreciate if you give me some hints that how can I write a python layer that creates this matrix and send it as third parameter to InfoGainLoss layer? I drew a schematic here, Is it correct? If yes, how to write the python layer for this? I already read some codes online but still have confusion on `setup`,`reshape`,`forward` functions.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNu]7a.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python layer is quite similar to an input layer: It has no backward propagation, which makes it easy to implement. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34996628/1714410) for more details.

Your layer expects `"label"` bottom, and produced `"H"` matrix as top:

layer {
     name: "classWeightH"
     bottom: "label"
     top: "H"
     type: "Python"
     python_param {
       module: # file name where python code is
       layer: "classWeightHLayer"
     }
   }

The python code should look something like:

```
import sys, os, numpy as np
sys.path.insert(0, os.environ['CAFFE_ROOT']+'/python')
import caffe
class classWeightHLayer(caffe.Layer):
  def setup(self,bottom,top):
    assert len(bottom)==1, "expecting exactly one input"
    assert len(top)==1, "producing exactly one output"
    # you might want to get L - the number of labels as a parameter...

  def reshape(self,bottom,top):
    top[0].reshape(1,1,L,L) # reshape the output to the size of H

  def forward(self,bottom,top):         
    labels = bottom[0].data
    H = np.zeros((1,1,L,L), dtype='f4') 
    # do your magic here...
    top[0].data[...] = H    

  def backward(self, top, propagate_down, bottom):
    # no back-prop for input layers
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all your supports and helps here. You are always helpful.