# How to write a caffe python data layer with preload?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

How to write an asyncronous data layer to preload batches while other processing is performed? Are there some example codes? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways you can achieve what you want. I'll try and sketch one option here.

The overall view of the system is: you have `n` `Loader`s asynchronously loading data and feeding a queue. The layer then reads `batch_size` items from the queue and feed the net in the `forward()` function.

```
import caffe, multiprocessing

class Loader(multiprocessing.Process):
  def __init__(self, outq, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Loader, self).__init__()
    self.daemon = True
    self.outq = outq
    self.start()  # start working

  def run(self):
    while True:  # read and never stop at all!
      try:
        # do your magic here
        # assuming you load x,y pairs
        self.outq.put((x[None, ...], y[None, ...]))  # add singleton "batch" dimension
      except Exception as e:
        # handle errors?
        pass

 class MultiProcessInputLayer(caffe.Layer):
   def setup(self, bottom, top):
     # verify no bottoms, right number of tops etc.
     self.dataQ = multiprocessing.Queue()
     for _ in xrange(n):
       Loader(self.dataQ)  # start n Loaders
     # some other stuff here...

   def reshape(self, bottom, top):
     # reshape the inputs to the right sizes

   def forward(self, bottom, top):
     for i in xrange(batch_size):
       item = self.dataQ.get()
       top[0].data[i, ...] = item[0]
       top[1].data[i, ...] = item[1]

   def backward(self, top, propagate_down, bottom):
     pass  # no backward for data layer
```

Some tips and tricks I learned the hard way:
1. Use `multiprocessing` and not `threading` package because of the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).
2. Sometimes (e.g. if `batch_size` is very large) it will take very long for `forward()` to read item by item from the Queue to form each batch. In that case, you might add another `multiprocessing.Process` that will async read `batch_size` items from `self.dataQ` and write whole batches to `self.batchQ`. Then `forward()` will only wait for a *single* item from `self.batchQ` at each call.
3. Take care not to copy the data around too much. Working with large images/labels can make all these copying into a bottleneck.

Comment: Hi, @Shai Thank you very much, you really helped me a lot. Can you provide a more Specific Example? For example, how to use your code to implement the ImageData layer, i.e., read images and labels from a text file (img_path, img_label). I don't know how to maintain the index and how to shuffle the list after every epoch in this multiprecessing setting. Thank you very much.

Comment: @kli_nlpr you can add another `multiprocessing.Process` that dispatch the image/label list to the `Loader`s. This process will shuffle after every epoch and do all the bookkeeping