# Why is training using custom python layer in Pycaffe is extremely slow?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I created a custom layer in python so that I can feed the data directly.
but I noticed it runs extremely slow and the GPU usage is at most 1% ( the memory is allocated, i.e. I can see that when I run the script, it allocates 2100MB VRAM and terminating the training, frees around 1G.
I'm not sure if this is an expected behavior or I'm doing something wrong.
Here is the script I wrote (based on [this former pr](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/3471/files)) :

```
import json
import caffe
import numpy as np
from random import shuffle
from PIL import Image


class MyDataLayer(caffe.Layer):

    """
    This is a simple datalayer for training a network on CIFAR10.
    """

    def setup(self, bottom, top):

        self.top_names = ['data', 'label']

        # === Read input parameters ===
        params = eval(self.param_str)

        # Check the paramameters for validity.
        check_params(params)

        # store input as class variables
        self.batch_size = params['batch_size']

        # Create a batch loader to load the images.
        self.batch_loader = BatchLoader(params, None)

        # === reshape tops ===
        # since we use a fixed input image size, we can shape the data layer
        # once. Else, we'd have to do it in the reshape call.
        top[0].reshape(self.batch_size, 3, params['im_height'], params['im_width'])
        # this is for our label, since we only have one label we set this to 1
        top[1].reshape(self.batch_size, 1)

        print_info("MyDataLayer", params)

    def forward(self, bottom, top):
        """
        Load data.
        """
        for itt in range(self.batch_size):
            # Use the batch loader to load the next image.
            im, label = self.batch_loader.load_next_image()

            # Add directly to the caffe data layer
            top[0].data[itt, ...] = im
            top[1].data[itt, ...] = label

    def reshape(self, bottom, top):
        """
        There is no need to reshape the data, since the input is of fixed size
        (rows and columns)
        """
        pass

    def backward(self, top, propagate_down, bottom):
        """
        These layers does not back propagate
        """
        pass


class BatchLoader(object):

    """
    This class abstracts away the loading of images.
    Images can either be loaded singly, or in a batch. The latter is used for
    the asyncronous data layer to preload batches while other processing is
    performed.

    labels:
    the format is like : 
    png_data_batch_1/leptodactylus_pentadactylus_s_000004.png 6
    png_data_batch_1/camion_s_000148.png 9
    png_data_batch_1/tipper_truck_s_001250.png 9
    """

    def __init__(self, params, result):
        self.result = result
        self.batch_size = params['batch_size']
        self.image_root = params['image_root']
        self.im_shape = [params['im_height'],params['im_width']]

        # get list of images and their labels.
        self.image_labels = params['label']
        #getting the list of all image filenames along with their labels
        self.imagelist = [line.rstrip('\n\r') for line in open(self.image_labels)]
        self._cur = 0  # current image
        # this class does some simple data-manipulations
        self.transformer = SimpleTransformer()

        print ("BatchLoader initialized with {} images".format(len(self.imagelist)))

    def load_next_image(self):
        """
        Load the next image in a batch.
        """
        # Did we finish an epoch?
        if self._cur == len(self.imagelist):
            self._cur = 0
            shuffle(self.imagelist)

        # Load an image
        image_and_label = self.imagelist[self._cur]  # Get the image index
        #read the image filename
        image_file_name = image_and_label[0:-1]
        #load the image
        im = np.asarray(Image.open(self.image_root +'/'+image_file_name))
        #im = scipy.misc.imresize(im, self.im_shape)  # resize

        # do a simple horizontal flip as data augmentation
        flip = np.random.choice(2)*2-1
        im = im[:, ::flip, :]

        # Load and prepare ground truth

        #read the label
        label = image_and_label[-1]
        #convert to onehot encoded vector
        #fix: caffe automatically converts the label into one hot encoded vector. so we only need to simply use the decimal number (i.e. the plain label number)
        #one_hot_label = np.eye(10)[label]

        self._cur += 1
        return self.transformer.preprocess(im), label


def check_params(params):
    """
    A utility function to check the parameters for the data layers.
    """
    required = ['batch_size', 'image_root', 'im_width', 'im_height', 'label']
    for r in required:
        assert r in params.keys(), 'Params must include {}'.format(r)


def print_info(name, params):
    """
    Ouput some info regarding the class
    """
    print ("{} initialized for split: {}, with bs: {}, im_shape: {}.".format(
        name,
        params['image_root'],
        params['batch_size'],
        params['im_height'],
        params['im_width'],
        params['label']))


class SimpleTransformer:

    """
    SimpleTransformer is a simple class for preprocessing and deprocessing
    images for caffe.
    """

    def __init__(self, mean=[125.30, 123.05, 114.06]):
        self.mean = np.array(mean, dtype=np.float32)
        self.scale = 1.0

    def set_mean(self, mean):
        """
        Set the mean to subtract for centering the data.
        """
        self.mean = mean

    def set_scale(self, scale):
        """
        Set the data scaling.
        """
        self.scale = scale

    def preprocess(self, im):
        """
        preprocess() emulate the pre-processing occuring in the vgg16 caffe
        prototxt.
        """

        im = np.float32(im)
        im = im[:, :, ::-1]  # change to BGR
        im -= self.mean
        im *= self.scale
        im = im.transpose((2, 0, 1))

        return im

    def deprocess(self, im):
        """
        inverse of preprocess()
        """
        im = im.transpose(1, 2, 0)
        im /= self.scale
        im += self.mean
        im = im[:, :, ::-1]  # change to RGB

        return np.uint8(im)
```

And in my `train_test.prototxt` file I have :

```
name: "CIFAR10_SimpleTest_PythonLayer"
layer {
  name: 'MyPythonLayer'
  type: 'Python'
  top: 'data'
  top: 'label'
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
   }
  python_param {
    #the python script filename
    module: 'mypythonlayer'
    #the class name
    layer: 'MyDataLayer'
    #needed parameters in json
    param_str: '{"phase":"TRAIN", "batch_size":10, "im_height":32, "im_width":32, "image_root": "G:/Caffe/examples/cifar10/testbed/Train and Test using Pycaffe", "label": "G:/Caffe/examples/cifar10/testbed/Train and Test using Pycaffe/train_cifar10.txt"}'
  }
}

layer {
  name: 'MyPythonLayer'
  type: 'Python'
  top: 'data'
  top: 'label'
  include {
    phase: TEST
   }
  python_param {
    #the python script filename
    module: 'mypythonlayer'
    #the class name
    layer: 'MyDataLayer'
    #needed parameters in json
    param_str: '{"phase":"TEST", "batch_size":10, "im_height":32, "im_width":32, "image_root": "G:/Caffe/examples/cifar10/testbed/Train and Test using Pycaffe", "label": "G:/Caffe/examples/cifar10/testbed/Train and Test using Pycaffe/test_cifar10.txt"}'
  }
}
```

Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Your data layer is not efficient enough and it takes most of the training time (you should try `caffe time ...` to get a more detailed profiling). At each `forward` pass you are waiting for the python layer to read `batch_size` images from disk one after the other. This can take forever. 
You should consider using `Multiprocessing` to perform the reading at the background while the net is processing the previous batches: this should give you good CPU/GPU utilization.
See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48065550/1714410) for multiprocessing python data layer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to see how much time the forward pass takes, here are the results for 5 iterations : 
`FW took:  0.0030002593994140625
FW took:  0.003001689910888672
FW took:  0.0030007362365722656
FW took:  0.0030069351196289062
FW took:  0.002504110336303711`
I used time.time() before the forward loop and after it . I guess they are fine, and I should not be seeing such massive performance hit!

Answer (score 0):

Python layers are executed on CPU not the GPU so it's slow because things have to keep going between the CPU and GPU when training. That's also why you see low gpu usage because its waiting on the cpu to execute the python layer.

Comment: this is not the case here: the python layer is an input layer, there is no sync from GPU to CPU. In most input layers data is read via CPU/host/disk and only then sync to GPU mem for further processing.