# how to write caffe python layer with trainable parameters?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I want to learn how to write caffe python layers.
But I only find examples about very simple layers like [`pyloss`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/pycaffe/layers/pyloss.py).

How to write python caffe with trainable parameters?

For example, how to write a fully connected python layer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caffe: how to get the phase of a Python layer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34549743/caffe-how-to-get-the-phase-of-a-python-layer)

Comment: @Shai,  I don't think this two are the same question. My question is how to creat a python layer with parameters, for example, how to implement a python fully connected layers?

Comment: The other question is about writing a python layer with parameters - which is exactly the title of your question.

Comment: Thank you @Shai,   I will edit my question more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Caffe stores the layer's trainable parameters as a vector of `blobs`. By default this vector is empty and it is up to you to add parameters blobs to it in the `setup` of the layer. There is a simple example for a layer with parameters in [`test_python_layer.py`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/test/test_python_layer.py#L31).

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41481539/1714410) for more information about `"Python"` layers in caffe.